# Android RecyclerView Changes text to Image when scroll

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Can anyone please help me out here???

Problem statement: I am making a chat application that is almost ready in ChatActivity. Functionality is the user can send images and text together but while sending text it's fine. The problem starts when I am sending images. And after sending when I scroll up to my all the texts start to change into the recently sent image.

ChatActivity.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_light"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backArrow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back_arrow"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/backArrow"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/userName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lastSeen"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_light"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView7"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/profile_image"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userName" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="-22dp" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="left"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="395dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView7"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more"
                app:tint="@color/white" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/chatRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="611dp"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp">


        <View
            android:id="@+id/view14"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/follow_active_btn"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etMessage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Message"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="4"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendMessageImage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sendMessage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/etMessage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/view14"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/etMessage"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/comment"
            app:tint="@color/purple_500" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/sendMessageImage"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:padding="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sendMessage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/sendMessage"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sendMessage"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/clip"
            app:tint="@color/black" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

ChatAdapter.java -

```
package com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.media.Image;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.CenterCrop;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.RoundedCorners;
import com.bumptech.glide.request.RequestOptions;
import com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.Models.MessageModel;
import com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    ArrayList<MessageModel> list;
    Context context;

    int SENDER_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
    int RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE = 2;

    public ChatAdapter(ArrayList<MessageModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if(viewType == SENDER_VIEW_TYPE) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_sender, parent, false);
            return new SenderViewHolder(view);
        }
        else {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_receiver, parent, false);
            return new ReceiverViewHolder(view);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageModel message = list.get(position);

        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(message.getTimestamp());
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        String time = simpleDateFormat.format(ts.getTime());

        RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
        requestOptions = requestOptions.transforms(new CenterCrop(), new RoundedCorners(10));

        if(holder.getClass() == SenderViewHolder.class) {
            if (message.getMsgImg()!=null) {
                ((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderTextLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//                Picasso.get().load(message.getMsgImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderImage);
                Glide.with(((SenderViewHolder)holder).itemView.getContext()).load(message.getMsgImg()).apply(requestOptions)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderImage);
            } else {
                ((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderMsg.setText(message.getMessage());
                ((SenderViewHolder)holder).senderTime.setText(time);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (message.getMsgImg()!=null) {
                ((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverImageLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//                Picasso.get().load(message.getMsgImg()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverImage);
                Glide.with(((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).itemView.getContext()).load(message.getMsgImg()).apply(requestOptions)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverImage);
            } else {
                ((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverMsg.setText(message.getMessage());
                ((ReceiverViewHolder)holder).receiverTime.setText(time);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(list.get(position).getuId().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())) {
            return SENDER_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
        else {
            return RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    public class ReceiverViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView receiverMsg, receiverTime;
        ImageView receiverImage;
        ConstraintLayout receiverImageLayout;

        public ReceiverViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            receiverMsg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiverText);
            receiverTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiverTime);
            receiverImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.receiverImage);
            receiverImageLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageConstraintLayoutReceiver);
        }
    }

    public class SenderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView senderMsg, senderTime;
        ImageView senderImage;
        ConstraintLayout senderImageLayout;
        ConstraintLayout senderTextLayout;

        public SenderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            senderMsg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderText);
            senderTime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderTime);
            senderImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.senderImage);
            senderImageLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageConstraintLayoutSender);
            senderTextLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textConstraintLayoutSender);
        }
    }
}
```

ChatActivity.java -

```
package com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback;
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.Adapter.ChatAdapter;
import com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.Models.MessageModel;

import com.codinggeekers.lmsbeta.databinding.ActivityChatBinding;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ActivityChatBinding binding;

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    FirebaseStorage storage;

    ActivityResultLauncher<String> galleryLauncher;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        dialog.setTitle("Sending Image...");
        dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        // Sender and Receiver Ids
        final String senderId = auth.getUid();
        String receiveId = getIntent().getStringExtra("userId");
        String userName = getIntent().getStringExtra("userName");
        String profilePic = getIntent().getStringExtra("profilePic");


        binding.userName.setText(userName);
        Picasso.get().load(profilePic).placeholder(R.drawable.avatar).into(binding.profileImage);

        binding.backArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, UsersChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        final ArrayList<MessageModel> messageModels = new ArrayList<MessageModel>();

        final ChatAdapter chatAdapter = new ChatAdapter(messageModels, this);
        binding.chatRecyclerView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        binding.chatRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        binding.chatRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        final String senderRoom = senderId + receiveId;
        final String receiverRoom = receiveId + senderId;

        database.getReference().child("Chats")
                .child(senderRoom)
                .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        messageModels.clear();
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                            MessageModel model = snapshot1.getValue(MessageModel.class);
                            messageModels.add(model);
                        }
                        chatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });

        binding.sendMessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String message = binding.etMessage.getText().toString();
                if (message.matches("")) {

                } else {
                    final MessageModel model = new MessageModel(senderId, message, "text");
                    model.setTimestamp(new Date().getTime());
                    binding.etMessage.setText("");
                    database.getReference().child("Chats")
                            .child(senderRoom)
                            .push()
                            .setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Void unused) {
                            database.getReference().child("Chats").child(receiverRoom).push().setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(@NonNull Void unused) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        binding.sendMessageImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                galleryLauncher.launch("image/*");
            }
        });

        galleryLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(), new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityResult(Uri result) {
                dialog.show();
                final StorageReference reference = storage.getReference().child("chats")
                        .child(senderRoom).child(new Date().getTime() + "");
                reference.putFile(result).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        reference.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                final MessageModel model = new MessageModel(senderId, new Date().getTime(), uri.toString(), "image");
                                database.getReference()
                                        .child("Chats")
                                        .child(senderRoom)
                                        .push()
                                        .setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                        database.getReference().child("Chats").child(receiverRoom).push().setValue(model).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                                                dialog.dismiss();
                                                binding.sendMessageImage.setImageURI(Uri.EMPTY);
                                                Intent intent = getIntent();
                                                finish();
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        binding.userName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this, FriendsProfileActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("userName", userName);
                intent.putExtra("userId", receiveId);
                intent.putExtra("profilePic", profilePic);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **600 (six hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the suggestion, I will

Answer (score 0):

ItemViewType should start at 0.

Try to change them to this:

```
    int SENDER_VIEW_TYPE = 0;
    int RECEIVER_VIEW_TYPE = 1;
```

Comment: Hi simon5678, 
I tried this and it is solving my half problem which is while scrolling images is not getting duplicated but one issue resumes and that is while sending any text, That text is actually shown up as an image previously send. However, when I pressed back and reopened the ChatActivity, It's showing up text which is not changing while scroll